# Why is this giving me a illegal operands errors?

Tags: lc3

I'm trying to write a code in lc3 that will output a block letter using different ASCII characters. When I try to compile my code, I get a ton of errors in the first pass stating I have illegal operands and I'm not sure why.

Here's my code, FONT_DATA points to a bunch of .FILL lines representing the different ASCII characters which I haven't included here:

;Creates the offset needed to find the 16 rows corresponding to the x5002 input

```
        .ORIG x3000
        LDI R6,LETTER
        AND R8,R8,#0
        ADD R8,R8,#16
```

MULTIPLY    ADD R8,R8,#0

```
        BRz ENDOFFSET
        ADD R6,R6,R6
        ADD R8.R8,#-1
        BRnzp MULTIPLY
```

;Starts the code for the counters

ENDOFFSET   ADD R2,R6,FONT_DATA

```
        LDR R5,R2,#0
        AND R3,R3,#0
        ADD R3,R3,#16
```

ROWCHECK    BRz DONE

```
        AND R4,R4,#0
        ADD R4,R4,#8
```

ROW         BRz ROWDONE

;starts code for printing the characters
;this code will print anything with value 0

```
        LDR R5,R5,#0            
        BRn CHARACTER
        LDI R0,NEGCHAR
        OUT
        BRnzp ENDPRINT
```

;this code will print anything with value 1

CHARACTER   LDI R0,CHAR

```
        OUT
        BRnzp ENDPRINT
```

;this will shift the string and decrement the R4 counter

ENDPRINT    ADD R5,R2,R2

```
        ADD R4,R4,#-1
        BRnzp ROW
```

;This will start the next row and increment the string value

ROWDONE     ADD R2,R2,#1

```
        ADD R3,R3,#-1
        BRnzp ROWCHECK
```

DONE        HALT

CHAR    .FILL   x5000

NEGCHAR .FILL   x5001

LETTER  .FILL   x5002

Here's my error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya6QJ.png)

Basically I get "illegal operands for AND" on line 11, and "illegal operands on ADD" for lines 11, 13, 16, and 21. In the first pass

Answer (score 0):

Alright

`ADD R8,R8,#16`

Firstly the lc-3 has only 8 registers. They are named R0-R7. R8 isn't a valid register.

Secondly the #16 is too big of an immediate value for use with the ADD instruction. The range of values supported needs to fit in 5 bits. That means that the minimum is -16 and the maximum is 15 as these are the numbers you can represent as a 5 bit 2's complement number.

That applies to other instructions where you used R8, or an immediate value higher than 15.

Next this instruction `ADD R2,R6,FONT_DATA`

Add only accepts a hardcoded number in the immediate value version of the instruction. I suppose you are trying to add the contents of the label pointed to by FONT_DATA and add it to R6. You will need to use the LD instruction to load the value at that address into a register then you can use the ADD instruction with 2 registers.